# Java lambda throwing NPE when sorting

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-stream, comparator

I have the following code :

```
private List<CategoryModel> getReserveStockRuleMaxPriorityNavigationCategoryModel (Collection<CategoryModel> categoryModels){
        return categoryModels.stream()
                .map(NavigationCategoryModel.class::cast)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(NavigationCategoryModel::getReserveStockRuleSetCategoryPriority, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder())))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(navigationCategoryModel -> navigationCategoryModel.getReserveStockRuleSet().getCode(),Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

With this , my goal is to make two sorts , first one ordering reverse according to the reserveStockRuleSetCategoryPriority INT and then , place at the end of the list the NavigationCategoryModel that has the attribute reserveStock.code to null.

However , i'm getting NPE because in this category list I can receive NavigationCategoryModels with the attribute reserveStockRuleSet to null .

I don't want to filter and exclude the ones that are null from the sort because I WANT to place them at the end of the list

An example input would be :

```
NavCatModel priority : 500 , null reserveStockRuleSet
NavCatModel priority : 100 , NOT NULL reserveStockRuleSet
NavCatModel priority : 300 , null reserveStockRuleSet
NavCatModel priority : 200 , NOT NULL reserveStockRuleSet
```

Expected result after both sorts :

```
NavCatModel priority : 200 , NOT NULL reserveStockRuleSet
NavCatModel priority : 100 , NOT NULL reserveStockRuleSet
NavCatModel priority : 500 , null reserveStockRuleSet
NavCatModel priority : 300 , null reserveStockRuleSet
```

How can I modify this lambda in order to achieve this inputs/outputs example?

Comment: have a look at https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-java-collections-comparator-thencomparing.html because calling ```.sorted``` two times will not achieve what you intend to do. Also, preventing null on getters could be something like this I guess: ```.sorted(nullsFirst(comparing(Object::getSomething, nullsFirst(naturalOrder())))
                        .thenComparing(nullsFirst(comparing(Object::getSomething, nullsFirst(naturalOrder())))))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By having two `.sorted` calls on a stream, you are not chaining two comparators. The last one simply wins. You need to use `thenComparing` for this.

`Comparator.nullsLast` works when the mapper function maps an element to null. It doesn't work when the mapper throws a NPE.

In other words, in `navigationCategoryModel.getReserveStockRuleSet().getCode()`, it will work if `getCode()` returns null; not when `getReserveStockRuleSet` returns a null. You have to explicitly check for null in the computation.

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(NavigationCategoryModel::getReserveStockRuleSetCategoryPriority, 
                    Comparator.reverseOrder())
                    .thenComparing(navigationCategoryModel -> 
                                    navigationCategoryModel.getReserveStockRuleSet() != null 
                                            ? navigationCategoryModel.getReserveStockRuleSet().getCode() 
                                            : null, 
                            Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
```

Note: I have removed `Comparator.nullsLast(..)` for the first comparator assuming it is a primitive int and cannot be null.